# create LED using threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, led

I am trying to create a board which has multiple RGB LEDs mounted on it as shown in the figure.

[image]

I created the LED's using the following

```
this.light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity, distance, decay);
this.light.name = 'rgb-light';
this.led_group.add(this.light);

let textureGlow  = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('images/led1.png');
var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.8,
  emissive: this.light.color,
  color: this.light.color,
  wireframe: false,
  emissiveMap: textureGlow

});

let led_geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 1.6, 5);
let led_mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff
});

let led_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(led_geo, led_mat);
this.led_group.add(led_mesh);

this.ledsource = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(1.7, 1.7, 1), sphereMaterial);
this.ledsource.name = 'rgb-led';
```

But I would like them to be bright and glow as a normal LED would in physical world. Can I get any pointers on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: [here](http://dkobozev.github.io/webgl/led_cube/) is an example of LEDs

Comment: Keep in mind that lights are simply light sources. They don't take up any physical space or have physical attributes. In order to create a glow effect, you'll need to perform tricks such as textures (prisoner's example), or use shaders as Cherkesgiller suggested.

Comment: @prisoner849 I saw that example but the framerate is very very low.. and I would be switching the lights faster than what is being used in that example.

Comment: @Lonewolf you're free to use shaders for better performance

Comment: I don't know anything about webgl. When I started off with this project I was hoping to finish it very fast. But even with libraries like three.js, it seems like I have to dig into webgl to accomplish it :( . It probably is good time I learnt a bit about webgl.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to your question. But you can use shaders, Some postProccessing effects, volumetric lights and etc to achieve this. It is very big topic to discuss here. BTW there are a lot of examples which use better lighting techniques.  Here is a youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoSUX1KNiIU) from bkcore that use volumetric lights.